# Product cannibalization - Would affinity analysis help?

Tags: probability, bayesian, recommender-system, association-rules

We send an email to our customers to advertise 3-4 products every day.

Supposing that today's email is advertising three products (product A, product B, product C), the customer is given four options:

1. purchase A
2. purchase B
3. purchase C
4. make no purchase

Each choice is mutually exclusive i.e. each customer can make at most one purchase per day.  This is because of the nature of the business, which is subscription-based.

Every day we advertise different products and some products are advertised with more frequency than others.

We want to test if certain products cannibalize others, for example if customers that like A also like B, it would be wise not to advertise both products on the same day.

I am exploring affinity analysis to measure support, confidence and lift for each product pair - the issue is however that some products are more likely to be purchased simply because they are advertised more frequently than others.

Any suggestions on how to go about it?

EDIT: We can assume that customers can only make purchases via email.

Comment: Is the intuition that by including both A and B, you are decreasing variety of your offerings and losing some customers who don't care for A and B?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Is the only way to buy through the email? How many products are there?

Comment: 1) They can only buy through the email - I have edited my question to add this

2) There are hundreds of products in the inventory, but each day customers can only buy one of those 3-4 products that we advertise every day. We tend to rotate the products displayed (to avoid that products are advertised twice in the same week, for example).

Comment: Are there other variables, like prices, or buyer or product characteristics? Do you see the same buyer multiple times?

Comment: Price is the same across all the items. Since it is a subscription-based business, customers are generally loyal and many make purchase every day; however there are some customer segments that purchase less frequently than others.